# Unable to Initialize successive select in Angular JS 2

Tags: angularjs

I have created a [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ogsxftjv/1/) for showcasing the issue that in selects which are dependent on other selects for their values(I like to call them successive selects)

I am unable to assign an initial value to a successive select. 
Like
**HTML**

```
<select ng-model="car.brand" ng-options="brand for brand in brands" ng-change="selectedBrand(car.brand)"></select>
<select ng-model="car.model" ng-options="model.name for model in cars[carIndex]"></select>
<input type="text" ng-model="car.model.capacity">
```

**JS**

```
$scope.brands = ['Ford', 'Honda', 'Hyundai', 'Mahindra',
    'Maruti Suzuki', 'Nissan', 'Renault', 'Skoda', 'Tata', 'Toyota', 'Volksvagen'
  ];
$scope.selectedBrand = function(brand) {
    console.log(brand);
    $scope.carIndex = $scope.brands.indexOf(brand);
  }
$scope.cars[0] = [{
    name: "Figo",
    capacity: 45
  }, {
    name: "Ecosport",
    capacity: 52
  }, {
    name: "Fiesta",
    capacity: 45
  }, {
    name: "Endeavour",
    capacity: 71
  }];

/*My Attempt*/
/*Successful*/
$scope.car.brand = $scope.brands[0];
/*Unsuccessful*/
 $scope.car.model = $scope.cars[0][0].name;
```

**QUESTION**
How do I initialize the second select and the input box dynamically when  the first select is used?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, you should set `carIndex`. And  `car.model` must be set to the type same as  `model` in `<select ng-options=".. for model in ..`

```
 $scope.carIndex=0;
 $scope.car.brand = $scope.brands[0];
 $scope.car.model = $scope.cars[0][0];
```

Comment: You saved my life here... Thanks a ton Serg